# Dfference between float and double

Tags: c++, floating-point

First code

```
    double pi=3.14159,a=100.64;
cin>>a;
double sum=(a*a)*pi;
cout <<fixed<<setprecision(4)<<"Value is="<<sum<<endl;
return 0;
```

the value is =31819.3103
second code

```
    float pi=3.14159,a=100.64;
float sum=(a*a)*pi;
cout <<fixed<<setprecision(4)<<"Value="<<sum<<endl;
return 0;
```

the value is =31819.3105
why the difference between two value ?

Comment: Why shouldn't there be?

Comment: Try to google it first?

Comment: Start here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Those variable types are not stored decimal. Does that explain it to you?

Comment: Why would there be two types `float` and `double` if they gave the same results?

Answer (score 1):

In both `float` and `double` (and all other floating-point types available in `c++`) the values are represented in floating-point form: to store `x = m * 2^p`, the values `m` and `p` are written to memory.

Obviously, not all real numbers can be represented in such form (especially given that the maximum length of `m` and `p` is limited). All the numbers that cannot be represented in such form are rounded to one of the nearest neighbours. Since both 3.14159 and 100.64 are infinite fractions in the binary system, both of them are rounded, and when you write `a = 3.14159`, `a` is really a bit different.

Subsequently, the result of some expression calculation on the rounded values is not precise and may vary if we use a different rounding mode, that's why you see the result you see.

Probably, the value obtained by using `double` is more precise as `double` on most architectures and compilers uses more digits of mantissa. To achieve even more precision, consider using `long double`.

Comment: True in practice (and upvoted), but the C++ standard does not actually enforce use of IEEE-754 or a similar mantissa+exponent format. It's the most common by far, but not necessary.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for pointing